# C++ included class is not recognized by another class

Tags: c++, class, include

I am trying to do Bootstrapping with C++. I have a `Bootstrapping` class which carries out sampling calculations, a `Sample` class which stores the results:

In `Sample.h` file

```
class Sample
{
      // do something
};
```

In `Bootstrapping` class

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Bootstrapping
{
 private:
    vector<Sample> sample_list;    // Here the problem happens

   // do something
};
```

In `main.cpp` file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Bootstrapping.h"
#include "Sample.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // do something
}
```

When I debug above codes, the compiler pops an error in `Bootstrapping` class, which says `identifier "Sample" is undefined`. But I obviously already included it in `main`!

Can anyone help me out of this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you include Sample.h in the bootstrapping class declaration header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should re-order the headers.

```
#include "Sample.h"
#include "Bootstrapping.h"
```

Comment: This works, but depending on headers to be included in a certain order is bad practice. Since the definition of 'Bootstrapping' depends on the definition of 'Sample', Bootstrapping.h should include Sample.h. (Forward declarations won't work here.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to `#include "Sample.h"` in the `Bootstrapping.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

Sample.h included after Bootstrapping.h. Compiler processes code from beginning to end, so it knows nothing about Sample class while processing declaration of Bootstrapping class.
And of course you should include Sample.h in Bootstrapping.h to make this header independent of headers order.